# Deprecated NEST features causing problems in C#

Tags: c#, version, nest

I needed to upgrade from using NEST version="0.12.0.0" targetFramework="net40" to version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net452" in a project due to a newly imported assembly needing it.

I have an existing cs class that was referencing the older version of Nest and I can no longer build my solution. Is there either a way I can reference both version of NEST in the same project? Or can I rewrite the older code to use the newer version of NEST. The symbols it can no longer resolve are related to the ElasticClient, specifically:

```
ElasticClient _client = new ElasticClient(_settings);
var clusterHealth = _client.Health(HealthLevel.Cluster);
var nodesHealth = _client.NodeInfo(NodesInfo.All);
var indicesHealth = _client.Health(HealthLevel.Indices);
var indicesStats = _client.Stats();
```

Specifically where it's unable to resolve Health, HealthLevel, NodeInfo and Stats

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the API methods have changes slightly to better align with the APIs in Elasticsearch

```
var clusterHealth = client.ClusterHealth(h => h.Level(Level.Cluster));
var nodesHealth = client.NodesInfo();
var indicesHealth = client.ClusterHealth(h => h.Level(Level.Indices));
var indicesStats = client.ClusterStats();
```